# How do I change the default tabicon position?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I've add fragment title and icon as below. By default tab icons are positioned in upper. I want to keep these icons in left side. Is it possible to change position in following structure or do I need custom code ?

```
    // Add Fragments to adapter one by one
    adapter.addFragment(new Home_Screen(), "Home");
    adapter.addFragment(new YebformCover(), "Yeb");
    adapter.addFragment(new ServiceCover(), "Service");
    adapter.addFragment(new FeaturedCover(), "Feature");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_home);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_school);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_development);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_plan);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **set customView to tabs**.

Check out [setCustomView(View)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int)), that you need to apply to tabs.

Create custom layout file, inflate layout using `LayoutInflater` and set it to tabs -

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("Tab 1");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.your_icon, 0, 0, 0);
// Set layout to first tab
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```